# Heroku rake db:migrate failing - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My app is working fine locally and my push to Heroku was successful. But, when I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant AddWeightToExercises
```

Here is the failed migration:

```
class AddWeightToExercise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :exercises, :weight, :float
  end
end
```

edit: Thanks for the help everyone. The solution was to pluralize the class name to match the file name. Thanks for the help and quick responses.

Comment: This probably happens if you have renamed your migration.

Comment: As @ArslanAli indicates, this tends to happen when names of files and classes do not match ... what is the file name of your migration?

Comment: @craig.kaminsky The file name is 20150621165611_add_weight_to_exercises.rb, Should i change the file name or the class name?

Comment: That *should* be it (since the class is `AddWeightToExercise`). I'd change the class name over the file name as that file name correctly pluralizes the table (Exercises).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your migration file's name should correspond to `AddWeightToExercises`. It should be accordingly `xxxxxxxx_add_weight_to_exercises`, where `xxxxxxx` corresponds to a particular timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name uses "exercises" plural, but your class name is `AddWeightToExcercise` singular. The two need to be consistent for rails to dynamically load the appropriate class.